# How do you add a custom vertical scrollbar to a listbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to add a custom vertical scrollbar to listbox1, I have disabled the horizontal scrollbar and just want to add a custom vertical scrollbar using siticone (siticoneVScrollBar1)

the results I want is that I want to instead use siticoneVScrollBar1 instead of the default windows vertical scrollbar since the default one doesn't suit my WinForms application's UI. I plan to use siticoneVScrollBar1 because it is customizable.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IcPdbEOmeN4 does this help?

Comment: Hi, you may want to share some of you code here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i havent written any code at all yet for this mechanism because i dont know where to start